# Windows phone 8.1 architecture warnings

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Silverlight 8.1 projects with WinRT projects and I get warnings like the one below. Am I doing something wrong here?

> Warning   24  There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of
>   the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "Path to project", "ARM". This mismatch may cause runtime
>   failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture
>   of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the
>   processor architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Visual Studio 2013. Right click on project, select properties, and under the build tab, select platform target to ARM.